# Basic sorting of 2D Arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, columnsorting

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to sort a 2D array while maintaining consistency with the array's structure. For instance, I have an array say...

```
myArray[4][3] = {{"Tom", "yes", "yes"},
                 {"Bob", "yes", "no"},
                 {"Chris", "no", "no"},
                 {"Bill", "no", "yes"}};
```

That when sorted should translate to...

```
myArray[4][3] = {{"Bill", "no", "yes"},
                 {"Bob", "yes", "no"},
                 {"Chris", "no", "no"},
                 {"Tom", "yes", "yes"}};
```

If I am phrasing my question correctly, in essence, I am trying to move the entire row in ascending order based on the element located in column 0.

Comment: You need to sort a range of, start and end iterators to, three-element arrays, and a comparison function between three-element arrays, since that's what you're sorting and what you're sorting on.

Comment: It would be much easier if instead of 2D array you had `struct SomeStruct { std::string name; bool var1; bool var2; };` and then 1D array of that  struct `SomeStruct myArray[4] = {{"Bob", true, false}, ...};`

Comment: Why isn't that a `struct Person { std::string name; bool opt1, opt2; }; std::array<Person, 4>;` or `std::vector<Person>`? Add `Person::operator<=>` and you can just sort the array or vector.

Comment: What problem did you encounter when you tried to sort this? Admittedly, an array of pointers would be easier to sort, but there should be no issue sorting your data structure. The values to swap are more complex than typical, but once you have that, sorting proceeds as it would with any data type. (If you are having trouble writing the swap function, then that should be mentioned in the question.)

Comment: To illustrate why this question needs clarity: suppose I come to the conclusion that you have no idea how to write any sorting algorithm. What information in the question contradicts that conclusion? One might think that one would not attempt to sort a 2D array of strings before being able to sort a 1D array of integers, but  that is not a safe assumption to make around here. (There have been questions along the lines of "I started learning to program last week. How do I write an operating system?") So please, more information. Perhaps your sort attempt that failed at consistency?

Comment: I haven’t gotten to structures yet, I realize through some reading that they would be easier to work with. However, they’re currently beyond my scope.  

Currently I’ve been able to sort it as I need it by using vectors and sort() from <algorithm>. 

This is great and it seems to solve my problem for the time being, but I still would like to know how the format is for sorting this way with a 2D array. I can’t visualize it through my readings.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested, a `struct` makes this much simpler. It also keeps your relevant data together for you, as it appears that a row is all related to a single entry.

Here's some code that demonstrates the principle:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Client {
  std::string name;
  bool one = false;
  bool two = false;

  Client(std::string n, bool r, bool a) : name(n), one(r), two(a) {}
};

bool operator<(const Client& lhs, const Client rhs) {
  return lhs.name < rhs.name;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& sout, const Client& client) {
  return sout << std::boolalpha << client.name << ", " << client.one << ", "
              << client.two;
}

template <typename Container>
void print(const Container& c) {
  for (auto i : c) {
    std::cout << i << '\n';
  }
}

int main() {
  std::array<Client, 4> clients{{{"Tom", true, true},
                                 {"Bob", true, false},
                                 {"Chris", false, false},
                                 {"Bill", false, true}}};

  print(clients);
  std::sort(clients.begin(), clients.end());
  std::cout << "\n\n";
  print(clients);
}
```

Each row is now an object, which makes keeping track of a `client`, in this case, much easier than ensuring all the disparate data pieces travel together.

Because each row was compacted to an object, you now have a 1D array instead of a 2D array, and sorting those are trivial.

Here, I use `operator<()` instead of the new in C++20 `operator<=>()` because my compiler is giving me a hard time with the C++20 stuff generally (I need to check my version's compatibility and upgrade if possible).

Output:

```
Tom, true, true
Bob, true, false
Chris, false, false
Bill, false, true


Bill, false, true
Bob, true, false
Chris, false, false
Tom, true, true
```

Another note, and one that I didn't want to add code to keep the answer clean(er) would be to create types for the `bool`s using `enum class`es. This way, instead of trying to remember what the second `bool` is supposed to represent, you'd have the type name with a clear value instead. Again, it adds a bit more boilerplate, so I kept it out of this answer, but it is a huge help to code readability.

Answer (score 0):

> I still would like to know how the format is for sorting this way with a 2D array. I can’t visualize it through my readings.

Okay.

The tl;dr is, the C++ standard library is built to assume container elements are copyable with `operator=`, which raw C arrays are very much not, and to get past that with arrays as data elements like you've got here you need to tell C++ to use C++ semantics on them, with `std::array<const char*,3>` as its type.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <cstring>

std::array<const char *,3> myarray[] = {
    {"Tom", "yes", "yes"},
    {"Bob", "yes", "no"},
    {"Chris", "no", "no"},
    {"Bill", "no", "yes"}
};
int main()
{
    using namespace std;
#define λlr(expr) [](auto &l, auto &r) { return expr; }
    sort(begin(myarray), end(myarray), λlr(strcmp(l[0],r[0])<0));
    for ( auto &row : myarray )
        cout <<'\t'<<row[0] <<'\t'<<row[1] <<'\t'<<row[2] <<'\n';
}
```

edit: if you're stuck with the raw C arrays exactly as shown, with `const char *[4][3]` for your data type, you're going to have to use the C library for your sorting or get horribly cute with your iterators. With the C library and a C++ compiler you're going to have to reassure its type safety checking about the function you're passing:

```
static int strcmp0(const void*l, const void*r) { return strcmp(*(char**)l,*(char**)r); }
/*...*/
qsort(myarray, sizeof myarray / sizeof *myarray, sizeof *myarray, strcmp0);`
```

and to use C++'s sorting you do it by telling it to treat what the iterators point to as `std::array`s it can copy:

```
{ typedef array<const char*,3> *member;
  sort(member(begin(myarray)),member(end(myarray), λlr(strcmp(l[0],r[0])<0));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually sort your raw array directly if you need to. To do this, we use a indexing array that keeps track of `std::sort`'s swaps. This can be used to create an inversion array and then invert the original raw array with `std::swap`. The latter will make sure that the internal consistency is invariant.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <cstring>

template <std::size_t N, std::size_t M>
void sort(char const* (&a)[N][M]) {
  std::size_t idx[N] {}; // meaning: slot x wants entry idx[x]
  std::iota(std::begin(idx), std::end(idx), 0u); // 0, 1, 2, 3, ..., N-1

  std::sort(std::begin(idx),std::end(idx),[&](std::size_t const lhs, std::size_t const rhs) {
    return std::strcmp(a[lhs][0],a[rhs][0]) < 0;
  });

  // idx is now: 3, 1, 2, 0

  std::size_t inv[N] {}; // meaning: entry y wants to go to slot inv[y]
  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    inv[idx[i]] = i;
  }

  // inv is now: 3, 1, 2, 0

  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    while (inv[i] != i) { // keep permutating until a[i] has the correct entry
      std::swap(a[i], a[inv[i]]);
      std::swap(inv[i], inv[inv[i]]);
    }
  }
}
```

You can call this with your example array:

```
sort(myArray);
```

Although it doesn't immediately look like it, the last inversion loop (the one containing the while-loop) is actually linear in N (counting the number of swaps). Each swap moves *some* line to the final slot it has to end up in. So even if a single iteration of the outer for loop may swap a lot of entries around, each of those is final and eventually it will move the correct entry to slot `i`.